# Redirect from http to https on IIS 10.0

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting

I have an aspx web app accessed via http://domain/web.aspx. This web app uses port 80 and http://domain:80/web.aspx works OK. I would like to redirect all calls to https://domain:82/web.aspx. I've tried using the rewrite rule

```
<rule name="HTTPS force" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*):80$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:82" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

in web.config in the same folder as web.aspx but this has no effect. What rewrite rule do I need to use?

Comment: Try using failed request trace to see detailed request information and you will find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following as input:

```xml
<rule name="HTTPS force" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Not sure if you want the `:80` there in the URL? If so, it can be added to my example too. Taken from here: [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules - https, www, and more](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/#redirect-to-https).

Answer (score -1):

Found this rule worked

```
<rule name="HTTPS force" enabled = "true" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://domain/Web.aspx" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain:82/Web.aspx"/>
            </rule>
```

Comment: This rule is impossible to work as the content of `HTTP_HOST` never can match that pattern. You'd better enable FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: The rule as shown worked OK in Web.config as follows `<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled = "true" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://domain.com.au/Web.aspx" />
             </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com.au:82/Web.aspx"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>`